# How to process a column (class - string) using the method rjust in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, methods, just

The main problem is, I can't process the column using the specified method rjust(), while I can perfectly apply it in ordinary strings

Sample Input:

```
8 11 123
```

Sample Output (what I expect):

```
008
011
123
```

I have tried so far:

```
Str = '8 11 123'
Str_split = Str.split(' ')
#print (Str_split)
Strjoin = '\n'.join(Str_split)
print (Strjoin.rjust(3, '0'))
```

```
#8
11
123
```

And yes, I know it's possible to carry out with help of loop for:

```
Str = '8 11 123'
Str_split = Str.split(' ') 
print (Str_split) #['8', '11', '123']
for item in Str_split: 
    print (item.rjust(3, '0'))
```

But I need to fullfill task without loop, only with string methods

Comment: If you can't use an explicit loop, can you use `map` and/or list comprehensions?

Comment: I can use both of them in theory, but for the task, accoding to my tutor, I'm allowed to use only string methods, map is suited, but not list comprehensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map()` instead of `for`-loop:

```py
s = "8 11 123"

s = "\n".join(map("{:>03}".format, s.split()))
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
008
011
123
```

---

Or:

```
s = "\n".join(map(lambda x: x.rjust(3, "0"), s.split()))
```

Comment: Thanks! The way is well-suited for the task!

Answer (score 1):

Call `rjust()` in the argument to `join()`

```
Strjoin = '\n'.join(s.rjust(3, '0') for s in Str_split)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `rjust` has trouble processing strings with newline '\n' character, although I don't know why. The workaround is to first adjust the strings (I use list comprehension to apply desired function to all elements of `str_split`) and then print it out joining with `\n`.

```
Str = '8 11 123'
Str_split = Str.split(' ')
str_temp = [string.rjust(3,'0') for string in Str_split]
Strjoin = '\n'.join(str_temp)
print(Strjoin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, using a *[list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)*; a *for-loop*.

```py
s = '\n'.join([x.rjust(3, '0') for x in input().split()])
```

And, here is an example, using a *[regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)*, and a *[lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions)*.

```py
import re
s = re.sub(r'\d{1,3}', lambda x: '0' * (3 - len(x.group())) + x.group(), input()).replace(' ', '\n')
```

Output

```
8 11 123
008
011
123
```